# Finding the intersection of an xy-plane in a 3D-Coordinate System

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I found the equation of a sphere that has a center of $(1,-12,8)$ with a radius of 10 and I got the following equation:

$(x-1)^2 + (y+12)^2 + (z-8)^2 = 100$

As for finding an intersection for the xy-plane I got this and it was the wrong answer:
$(x-1)^2 + (y+12)^2 = 100$

I assumed that it would be this because since it was an xy-plane, it wouldn't include the z-portion of the equation.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of $z$ in the $xy$-plane?

Comment: Your wrong answer occurs because you set $z-8 = 0$ and evaluated. While the value of the $z$ component at the center of your sphere is $8$, the sphere intersects the $xy$ axis in the plane $z=0$.

Comment: continuing with amWhy's point, $(x-1)^2+(y+12)^2=10^2$ is the intersection of the sphere with the $z=8$ plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your answer amounts to is the circle at which the sphere intersects the plane $z=8$.

However, we're looking for the intersection of the sphere and the $x$-$y$ plane, given by $z=0.\;$ In other words, we're looking for all points of the sphere at which the $z$-component is $0$.

Thus we need to evaluate the sphere using $z = 0,\,$ which yields the circle $$\begin{align} (x-1)^2 + (y+12)^2 + (0-8)^2 = 100 &\iff (x-1)^2 + (y+12)^2 + 64 = 100\\ \\ &\iff (x-1)^2 + (y+12)^2 = 36 = 6^2\end{align}$$

Thus the intersection of the sphere and the $x$-$y$ plane gives a circle with center $(1, -12)$ and radius $6$.

Answer (score 2):

In the $xy$-plane, $z=0$, but note that you are looking at $(z-8)^2$ as one of the terms of your sphere.